# C# UDPClient pass variable as port value

Tags: c#, variables, port, udpclient

This is my code:

```
UdpClient server = new UdpClient(5001);
```

My question is: i want to pass the port value (5001), from an `int` variable. Is this possible?

Example:

`UDPClient server = new UDPClient(intvariable);`

Thank you!

Comment: var intvariable = 5001; var server = new UDPClient(intvariable);`

Comment: Did you try? Yes it's possible. What the problem?

Comment: I suppose you need to know something else too, like this...wasn't faster to compile and try?

Comment: I expected that parameter is ushort and you are asking for different type (int). But the definition of UDPClient(port) is with Int32 parameter and there is nothing special. So, what is the question/problem?

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of the UpdClient is Int32 so you can do so.

```
int variable = value;
UDPClient server = new UDPClient(variable);
```

Here's the definition of the [UpdClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the address and port in the constructor, just take a look at the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

So you could have

```
int portNumber = 12345;
string ipAddress = 127.0.0.1    //You can also use a web address instead.
UDPClient newClient - new UDPClient(ipAddress, portNumber);
```

Alternatively you can put nothing in the constructor and do the specify a destination when you connect. This allows you to get user input first rather than hard coding the address and port.

```
int portNumber = 12345;
string ipAddress = 127.0.0.1    //You can also use a web address instead.
UDPClient newClient - new UDPClient();
newClient.Connect(IpTextBox.text(), Convert.ToInt32(portNumberTB.Text() );
```

Remember if you are reading user input for your address and port then you will need error handling.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of `UdpClient` cannot tell the difference between `new UdpClient(1234)` and

```
int port = 1234; new UdpClient(port);
```

For that reason there cannot possibly be a difference. `1234` and `port` are expressions of the same value. That's the only thing that counts.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers.

The code you people gave me was correct. My code aswell.

My problem occurs in the declaration of the UDPClient objects. The declaration happens
during the initialization of a windows form application.